# Problematic Bison grammar not accepting a call of a call or anything after a call other than ;

Tags: parsing, syntax-error, bison, operator-precedence

I have some grammar here in Bison: https://pastebin.com/raw/dA2bypFR.
It's fairly long but not very complex.

The problem is that after a call, it won't accept anything other than `;` e.g `a(b)(c)` and is invalid, `a(b).c` is invalid, which both only accept a semicolon after the closing parenthesis.
`a(b)+c` is fine though.

I tried separating `call_or_getattr` into 2 where `.` has higer precedence than `(` but this meant that `a().b` was invalid grammar.

I also tried putting `call` and `getattr` into the definition for `basic_operand` but this resulted in a 536 shift/reduce errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last production reads as follows (without the actions, which are an irrelevant distraction):

```
call_or_getattr:
    basic_operand
|   basic_operand '(' csv ')'
|   basic_operand '.' T_ID
```

So those are postfix operators whose argument must be a `basic_operand`. In `a(b)(c)`, the `(c)` argument list is not being applied to a `basic_operand`, so the grammar isn't going to match it.

What you were looking for, I suppose, is:

```
call_or_getattr:
    basic_operand
|   call_or_getattr '(' csv ')'
|   call_or_getattr '.' T_ID
```

This is, by the way, very similar to the way you write productions for a binary operator. (Of course, the binary operator has a right-hand operand.)

Comment: Thank you! I feel really silly for not noticing this, given that all of the other left & right-associative binary operators use this pattern.